# How to implment SpanQuery with MultiFieldQuery in java using lucene

Tags: java, lucene, fuzzy-search

I currently want to implement SpanQuery with MultiFieldQuery for fuzzy phrasing but I have issues with it.

I have tried using MultiFieldQuery with BooleanQuery. It only works partially, it can search fuzzy phrase but the phrase does not follow any slop, for example, my index contains this "Check out these". When I search "Check out", it will return a hit and show this "Check out these". This is the result I want. However, when I search "Check these", it will also return a hit and show this "Check out these". In this case, it should fail because "out" is the second word.

I have also tried using SpanQuery. The above scenario will not happen if I using this method. However, I can only search for one field. Whereas I want to search with multiple fields.

```
private static TopDocs searchInFuzzyPhrase(String textToFind, String textToFind1, IndexSearcher searcher, int slop)
        throws Exception {
    // Create search query in phrase    
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    //multifield
    MultiFieldQueryParser query = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]
    { "FULL_NAME", "BRAND_NAME", "DISPLAY_NAME", "DISPLAY_NAME_SYNONYM" }, analyzer);
    query.setPhraseSlop(slop);
    BooleanQuery bQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(query.parse(textToFind + "~"), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .add(query.parse(textToFind1 + "~"), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
            .build();       
    //span
    SpanQuery[] clauses = new SpanQuery[2];
    clauses[0] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("DISPLAY_NAME", textToFind)));
    clauses[1] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("DISPLAY_NAME", textToFind1)));
    SpanNearQuery sQuery = new SpanNearQuery(clauses, slop, true);

    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(bQuery, 1);
    return hits;
}
```

Using the example earlier. "Check out these"
When I search "Check these" using MultiField + BooleanQuery, it will return a hit, however, it is not what I want.

When I search "Check these using SpanQuery, it will return a miss. This is what I want partially but it only applies to one field. I'm trying to apply it with many fields

Comment: Do you want to search for the same terms, with slop, in multiple fields? Sounds like a BooleanQuery composed of several SpanNearQuery is what you need

Comment: Also, which lucene version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, spans are working only on one field. It is kinda understandable, since there is hardly notion of positions between different fields.

You would need to follow the same code you have, you just need to extend it to all list of fields that you have.

E.g. for every string in your list `"FULL_NAME", "BRAND_NAME", "DISPLAY_NAME", "DISPLAY_NAME_SYNONYM"` you need to create `SpanQuery` as you did in the example and later combine all of them into one `BooleanQuery` with `Occur.SHOULD`